# Need advice on a cross join in hive to get wildcard words from a large table with 160 million rows?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I Have a huge table which has 160 million rows(words like like homeimprovement, cheaphomeimprovement, homeimprovementcheap etc), and a small table which has about 20K rows(homeimprovement), I am trying to find words like '%homeimprovement%' in the large table. So my desired output would give me back

```
homeimprovment homeimprovement
homeimprovement cheaphomeimprovement
homeimprovement homeimprovementcheap
```

Here is my current query, which is a cross join!
zd.domain gives me "homeimprovement"
lt.domain gives me similar domains

```
create table tmp_val_words
as 
select /*+ MAPJOIN(zd) */ 
zd.domain, lt.domain as zdd_domain,
from large_table lt, small_table zd 
where 
lt.sld like 
concat('%', zd.sld ,'%');
```

This is working great when the subset is small, like 100~, but when i tried running this for 3K or 4K its coming to about 99% and staying there for HOURS, eventually I am killing it. 
Is there any way to loop by taking 100 names at a time?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing cross join of two table. Why are you doing that. Please show the table structure so that we can help more.

Also indexing **lt.sld** will reduce time but it will take huge space as it is a part of large table but still considerable improvement.
Another thing, like clause is slow, if you know any specific pattern,then try to use that instead of searching this in complete sentence.

Comment: Since this is in hive, there wont be indexes. There is no specific pattern, I would have to find all available words.